# Trying to get property of non-object, but I can if I return it inmediatly

Tags: laravel, model

I have a good one here: 
Im developing an API and im returning my values with the following code:

```
public function apigetDrugs(){
    $arrayreturn= array();
    foreach (Drug::all() as $drug){
        $array=[
            "pharma"=>$drug->pharma->name,
            "id"=>$drug->id,
            "code"=>$drug->code,
            "CABMS_code"=>$drug->CABMS_code,
            "CABMSDF_code"=>$drug->CABMSDF_code,
            "name"=>$drug->name,
            "concentration"=>$drug->concentration,
            "presentation"=>$drug->presentation->name,
            "container"=>$drug->container->name,
            "previous_stock"=>$drug->previous_stock,
            "added"=>$drug->added,
            "added_transferred"=>$drug->added_transferred,
            "exit"=>$drug->exit,
            "exit_transferred"=>$drug->exit_transferred,
            "extra"=>$drug->extra,
            "user"=>$drug->user->name,

        ];
        $arrayreturn[]=$array;
    }

    return $arrayreturn;
    }
```

"Drug" model has relationships with Container, Presentation, User and Pharma. When I run my API I get the error "Trying to get property of non-object", so I decided to comment each line of code one by one and I found that I have the code running smoothly if I comment the pharma line, just like this:

```
    public function apigetDrugs(){
    $arrayreturn= array();
    foreach (Drug::all() as $drug){
        $array=[
            //"pharma"=>$drug->pharma->name,
            "id"=>$drug->id,
            "code"=>$drug->code,
            "CABMS_code"=>$drug->CABMS_code,
            "CABMSDF_code"=>$drug->CABMSDF_code,
            "name"=>$drug->name,
            "concentration"=>$drug->concentration,
            "presentation"=>$drug->presentation->name,
            "container"=>$drug->container->name,
            "previous_stock"=>$drug->previous_stock,
            "added"=>$drug->added,
            "added_transferred"=>$drug->added_transferred,
            "exit"=>$drug->exit,
            "exit_transferred"=>$drug->exit_transferred,
            "extra"=>$drug->extra,
            "user"=>$drug->user->name,

        ];
        $arrayreturn[]=$array;
    }

    return $arrayreturn;
    }
```

So I checked my relationships in the Pharma and Drug classes, nothing wrong that I can see with Drug:

```
class Drug extends Model
{
protected $guarded=[
"id",
"user_id"
];

use SoftDeletes;
protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
//
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo("App\User");
}
public function pharma(){
    return $this->belongsTo("App\Pharma");
}
public function presentation(){
    return $this->belongsTo("App\Presentation");
}
public function unit(){
    return $this->belongsTo("App\Unit");
}
public function container(){
    return $this->belongsTo("App\Container");
}
}
```

Nor with Pharma:

```
class Pharma extends Model
{
//
protected $guarded=[
    "id"
];

public function drugs(){
    $this->hasMany("App\Drug");
}
public function user(){
    $this->belongsTo("App\User");
    }
}
```

However I found something strange. I found this code will run without an issue and display perfectly the string that is intended to show:

```
public function apigetDrugs(){
    $arrayreturn= array();
    foreach (Drug::all() as $drug){
            dd($drug->pharma->name);
    }
    }
```

And it will even work if I replace "dd" function with "echo". Hope to hear what you think about this issue soon.
Luis

Comment: hi LuisE, `dd` will definitely kills whatever code runs after, so, your foreach will be executed once.. try to use `vardump` instead (yes, its not as fancy as laravel's).  anyway, make sure that `$drug->pharma` does already exists and the column is not nullable..

Comment: Yeah, I used dd just to know what I was putting out and it turns out to be a perfectly healthy Pharma object. The column is not nullable btw and if I replace the "$drug->pharma->name" with just "$drug->pharma" i will get something like this in my json: "{"pharma":{"id":1,"name":"Analgesia","user_id":1,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null}"

Answer (score 0):

Found my problem, one of my seeds had an invalid drug_id value.